# Adventure works 2012 'SalesOrder' query

Tags: sql-server

I have been given a task to analyse the ‘SalesOrderHeader’ table from the Adventure works 2012 database. So far, my code manages to display the orders in each month over the last 12 months, the month and year of the sale, the order number, the net value and who made the sale, however, I’m finding it hard to work out how to only show the 5 largest orders in each month. I also need to add an indicator to show the position (1-5) of each orders value. I've been struggling with this for a while and I was wondering if anyone could help? Below is the code I have so far:

```
select Ordermonth, OrderYear, SOH.SalesOrderNumber, SOH.SubTotal, SOH.TotalDue, P.FirstName, P.LastName

from ( select top (5)MONTH(OrderDate)as OrderMonth, YEAR(OrderDate)as OrderYear, SalesOrderNumber, SubTotal, TotalDue

        from  Sales.SalesOrderHeader

    where MONTH(OrderDate) = 1 and DATEDIFF(month, OrderDate, GETDATE()) <=12

        order by TotalDue desc) as A, Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH Join     Sales.SalesPerson SP on

        SOH.SalesPersonID = SP.BusinessEntityID Join Person.Person P On

        SP.BusinessEntityID = P.BusinessEntityID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend using a calculation to return the first of the month for each order so you get a `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype to query against rather than using separate columns for month and year.

As you need you need to show the top 5 orders for each month and also rank them in order then the solution is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function along with a suitable `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY`.

A query like the one below is a step in the right direction. In the query below the `ROW_NUMBER` window function is creating a row numbers for each `OrderMonth` group ordered by `SubTotal`. The CTE is then used in the outer query to restrict the results to only 5 per month and also apply your date period criteria.

However, if the requirements are to also display months which have no orders then it would require more work.

```
WITH Top5OrdersPerMonth AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, OrderDate), 0)
                              ORDER BY SubTotal DESC) AS LargestMonthlyOrders
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, OrderDate), 0) AS OrderMonth
        , *

    FROM
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader
)

SELECT
    *

FROM
    Top5OrdersPerMonth

WHERE
    LargestMonthlyOrders <= 5
    AND OrderMonth BETWEEN '20140201' AND '20150201'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions to rank rows by month and then filter by that rank:

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   MONTH(OrderDate) mnt ,
                        SubTotal ,
                        TotalDue ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MONTH(OrderDate) ORDER BY SubTotal DESC, TotalDue DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     Sales.SalesOrderHeader
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   rn <= 5
```